# Sqlinjection attack in C language

Tags: c++, c

I know sql-injection is a web based attack. but I want to know is it possible ? to write sql injection attack complete code in C language or I can take the code in C  (from any open source web site). I would introduce some invariants in that code and then check my invariants work fine or not in that particular program.

Comment: I am very thankful if anyone write his/her comments pleaseeeeeeeee.

Comment: I did not downvote, but your question is unclear regarding StackOverflow standards. You should visit the help center and specialy read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: It even works with human names: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3):

> I know sql-injection is a web based attack.

It is not. SQL injections can be done whenever user input gets included in SQL statements - this can be web based, but can also happen if you use the same input in an equally vulnerable desktop application communicating with a database. So yes, you could do that in C, or basically any programming language that can interact with a vulnerable software.